# Качество скриншота, сделанного через YouTube API

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

Делаю скриншот через `http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$link_youtube.'/0.jpg`, но он плохого качества. Как-то можно получить HD-качество скриншота?

Answer (score 9):

Все оказалось проще, чем казалось. Вот:

Стандартное изображение:
`http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/default.jpg`

Изображение высокого качества:
`http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg`

Изображение среднего качества:
`http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/mqdefault.jpg`

Изображение самого высокого качества, которое есть:
`http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/maxresdefault.jpg`